# Using "vw" to get 100% width headings

Tags: css, fonts, font-size, viewport-units

I have an h1 I want to fit the entire width of the viewport which consists of **13** characters in a monospaced font. After reading the [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/) article on viewport sized typography it seems like logically if I want to achieve this I simply have to set my h1's styles to:

```css
h1 {
    font-size: 13vw;
    font-family: monospace;
}
```

This however is rendering with a bit of space left over (highlight the text to see the white space):

[(There would be an image here but I don't have enough rep so click here for the JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/bluntfakie/dq11ywyy)

I have tried other sizes, `font-size: 14vw;` is slightly too big, `font-size: 13.99vw;` seems just right, but strangely `font-size: 13.999vw;` is still too big?

Can someone explain what is going on here? Why would each character of a 13 character length string in a monospaced font require *more than* (100/13)% of the viewport width to fit the entire viewport width?

Comment: Please link the relevant JSFiddle code editor.

Comment: Remove `/show/` from the fiddle url ? =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sup>Before I begin I'm just going to say that I'm not going to give you a workaround due to [issues I've raised in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31427295/using-vw-to-get-100-width-headings/31428084#comment50826940_31427860) on Stoyan Dekov's answer. Instead I'm only going to answer your question of *Can someone explain what is going on here?*</sup>

## `font-size` != `width`

The problem here is that you're assuming `font-size` is the same thing as `width`. It isn't. The [CSS Fonts Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-3/#font-size-prop) defines `font-size` as:

> ...the desired **height** of glyphs from the font.

This means that `font-size` is more comparable to `height` than it is to `width`.

This isn't specific to the `vw` unit, either. If you specify a `font-size` in pixels you'll also notice that the computed `width` does not match the `font-size`.

But even then it all depends on which `font-family` you're using anyway, as the same paragraph continues to say:

> For scalable fonts, the font-size is a scale factor applied to the EM unit of the font. (Note that certain glyphs may bleed outside their EM box.) For non-scalable fonts, the font-size is converted into absolute units and matched against the declared font-size of the font, using the same absolute coordinate space for both of the matched values.

The key words here being *scalable* and *non-scalable*.

Even if a non-scalable font was being used though, `13vw` would not reflect each character's *width*. This would never work with `vw`, but it may work with `vh` but only if the aspect ratio of each individual character matched the screen's aspect ratio.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is if a text is the exact same size as the parent container, it will span across a second line.

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    width:100px
}

h1 {
    font-family: monospace;
    width:100px;
}
```

That will cause the text to go onto a new line as they are both 100px. That's why 14vw is too big, but 13.99 is just enough: [Fiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dq11ywyy/2/)

However, you can use `text-align: justify;` to achieve what you want.

Take a look at this [Fiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dq11ywyy/3/).

Comment: This doesn't answer OPs question of *Can someone explain what is going on here?*. Furthermore you should note that this workaround is going to be both browser and device-specific. It will entirely depend on which font is used when declaring `monospace`. By default in Chrome on Windows this is the font Consolas, but on other browsers and devices this may be different. If we change the font to Lucida Console, for example, which is another monospace font in Windows, we'll see that the characters fall onto a new line: http://jsfiddle.net/dq11ywyy/4/